# Unable to display data in dataTable with serverside processing

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am not able add ( and hence show ) rows in dataTable while setting it serverSide parameter to true. I am using the following code. Printing on the console shows me the results desired, the rows are not populated with data. In the function build_falt_data given in the code, I need to do some processing with the code and add custom buttons against column values before displaying it in datatable.

Also I am getting one strange issue. The response is showing in indefinite loop. Please see the comments in code. I am not able to figure out the reason behind the same. Any help shall be appreciated.

```
     var self = $(this)
      var datatable =  $('#example').dataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/get_json_data.json',
                "method":"GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    //Method 1
                    console.log in build_falt_data shows results in infinite loop
                    datatable.fnAddData(self.build_falt_data(data));
                    // Method 2
                    var falt = self.build_falt_data(data);
                    //console.log(falt) yeilds true results with out loop repitition but unable to show the results in datatable rows
                    datatable.fnAddData(falt);
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            }
       });

      "build_falt_data": function( faltdata ) {
           falt_data = {};
           $.each( faltdata.data, function(index, faltList ) {
              falt_data.push(faltList.var1);
              falt_data.push(faltList.var2);
              falt_data.push(faltList.var3);
           });
           // In method 2 only, I am returning this array
           return falt_data;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code, but main reason is that you probably should not be using `fnAddData()` to add data to the table in `success` event handler.

Your code could be simplified as shown below.

```
var datatable = $('#example').dataTable({
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax": "/get_json_data.json",
   "columns": [
      {"data": "var1"},
      {"data": "var2"},
      {"data": "var3"}
   ]
});
```